# Parallel tests consuming ActiveMQ/JMS topic

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jms, activemq-classic

I have a `vm://localhost` in-memory activemq setting on an Spring Boot JMS project. 
My controllers send events to a particular topic, and some tests check the events are properly sent with `@JmsMessagingTemplate`. The problem is when I execute multiple tests at the same time, some pf them fail because they are getting the unexpected event.

How can I fix that? I tried to play with acknowledge modes, concurrent users, exclusive consumers, jms.listener.max-concurrency, activemq pool configuration...

Answer (score 1):

You should do one of the following:

1. Start an instance of in-memory ActiveMQ for each test (group of tests). For example you may use [embedded broker](http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-embed-a-broker-inside-a-connection.html) to spawn multiple instances.
2. Dynamically generate unique topic name for test and [create separate topic](http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-create-new-destinations.html) for each test.